# How to extract multiple regex matches from a string in java

Tags: java, regex

How do I form a regular expression to extract variables from a string which are of the format ${variable name}

Lets say I have a string like this :

```
hello ${ person } welcome to ${ university name}. you are enrolled in ${class}
```

and I need to extract these from the string

person ,

university name ,

class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to grab all the values inside `${...}`:

```
\$\{ *([\w -]+) *\}
```

**Java code:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{ *([\\w -]+) *\\}");
```

Use a `Matcher` object to grab all the groups using `while(matcher.find()) {...}` code snippet.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mB6bJ7/1)

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{*([\\w -]+)*\\}");
  
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher("hello ${person} welcome to ${universityname}. you are enrolled in ${class}");

m.groupCount() gives me 1 and only returns the last variable

Comment: As I said in answer you will need to use `while(matcher.find()) { System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); }`

Comment: ` while matcher.find(){
   System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
`

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You also can use RegEx that'll find all values in ${}

> \b*\u0024\{([\w\s]*)\}\B

where u0024 is a $ in unicode and test in [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/)

Here is an example of code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b*\u0024\\{([\\w\\s]*)\\}\\B");
String data = ...//String to parse
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
// check all occurrence
while (matcher.find()) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
MessageFormat.format(str, list);
```

where the str=hello {1} welcome to {2}. you are enrolled in {3}

and the just pass the values in the list

Comment: No that is not what i want. First i would want to know what each of the variables is. The string I gave is just an example string . I can have a string like  ${university} welcomes ${person} to ${class}.   The answer i am looking for is how do i form a regular expression